# How to invoke events of existing field once duplicated

Tags: acumatica

I have duplicated Scheduled Shipment field on SOOrder summary as per client's requirements. However, it does not call its field updated method from my extension class. How can I call its base method?

For instance, if you try to change Sched. Shipment date on Shipping Settings tab, it will give you a popup dialog box for confirmation. However, but if you change the Sched. Shipment in Summary section (duplicated field), it does not give any confirmation dialog box.

I have below code written but does not get called--

```html
 protected virtual void SOOrder_ShipDate_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
        {
            if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
                InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain under what circumstances you expect provided handler to get invoked? It would also help if you share screenshots of what you've done so far.

Comment: I would agree with Ruslan. What are you trying to accomplish might help you get a better answer. What does calling the base FieldUpdated give you for example?

Comment: Included image and elaborated little bit more, hope if that clarifies.

Comment: Make sure your field you added in the summary area has the CommitChanges="True" the same as the field below.

Comment: That was quick. Just missed that. Thank you Brendan.

Answer (score 0):

Make CommitChanges="True" for the fields.